# In Melachim (Book of Kings) Chapter 19: What is actually going on in paragraph 11

Tags: melachim-kings-book-of

What is g-d trying to show Elijah, What is the whole point of the boulders being broken and fire and chaos that Elijah beheld, I don't get it because it then continues to also say "but g-d was not in the wind or fire etc...

Can somebody please explain what is actually going on here, What is g-ds objective or was this occurrence just happenstance?